# Elixir Postgres ERROR 42501 when running mix ecto.setup?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying out a phoenix project ([source](https://github.com/shankardevy/mango)) but having trouble setting up DB.

When I run `mix ecto.setup` I am getting this error: `(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42501 (insufficient_privilege): permission denied to create extension "citext...`

I am aware there is an almost exact [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601420/postgrex-error-error-42501-insufficient-privilege-to-create-extension-citext) asking similar question, but that post has no answer.

I went to `psql` and ran `CREATE EXTENSION citext;`, but I am still having the same issue.

Can someone point me to the right place so I can setup the proper user privilege so I can run `mix ecto.setup` successfully?

I am running Phoenix v1.3.2 and elixir 1.6.2.

I also have another phoenix project that I can run `mix ecto.setup` successfully. I am listing part of the config/dev.exs below for comparison.

Inside rumbl/config/dev.exs (SUCCESSFUL)

```
# Configure your database
config :rumbl, Rumbl.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "rumbl_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

Inside mango/config/dev.exs (ERROR)

```
# Configure your database
config :mango, Mango.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "mango_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

The repo of the project I am having problem can be found [here](https://github.com/igghub/mango). Here is another phoenix project I have no problem with, maybe it would help: [here](https://github.com/igghub/rumbl)

Answer (score 3):

You have to be connected as a superuser to install the extension `citext`.

The reason is that this extension creates C functions, and that is restricted to superusers.

Comment: Noob question, but how can I be connected as a superuser in this context?

Comment: Use `psql` with the option `-U <name of a superuser>`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution. I think it is a combination of Laurenz' answer and me tinkering around.

I went to `psql` and listed all users `\l`, and found that my username, `iggy`, is listed as an owner

```
...
iggy                            | iggy     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 
...
```

I did `psql -U iggy` and ran `CREATE EXTENSION citext;`

I changed `username` inside `dev.exs`:

```
config :mango, Mango.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "iggy",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "mango_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

Then I ran `mix ecto.setup` and voila! It ran flawlessly. It is a little weird, because my other project has exact same `dev.exs` config and I had the username listed as `postgres` (it worked there) while only `iggy` works here.